# Is there a way to make Eclipse's code completion as good as XCode's?

Tags: c, eclipse, autocomplete

I just started making my first couple of apps for iOS, which involves using XCode for the first time. I'm amazed how effortless coding becomes with the code completion in this. Everything from data types, to function names, to syntax templates, the IDE will suggest to you and write it in if you choose. It makes coding so smooth, and means you never need to struggle to remember what you named some function, or what order the arguments come in.

Until now, I've been using Eclipse to code in C, as well as a little Java. I've seen how to modify the content assist options for Java such that it will give suggestions based on almost any input, which simulates what XCode does. But attempting to do the same thing under the preferences for the C/C++ editor, I'm unable to find similar settings.

Is there anything else natively I can do to configure Eclipse so that it will match, or at least come close to, the same level of code completion in XCode, or am I into plug-in territory? To be clear, I'm referring to the C/C++ editor in Eclipse (specifically C), which I want to imitate XCode's code completion functionality.

Comment: You could always write one...

Comment: For Eclipse to match XCode functionality you'd have to disable some features in Eclipse

Comment: @nathanhayfield Not a bad idea! Perhaps at some point I will. For now though I have no idea how to do it, and I have other priorities.

Comment: @ChrisGerken I'm not sure if your comment was meant to be snide or if you misunderstood me. I'm not looking for Eclipse to match XCode's functionality in general; I'm looking specifically for it to have XCode's code completion, which I find to be superior. I'm aware that there are many other areas, perhaps most, in which Eclipse is more powerful than XCode, but that's not what I was asking about.

Comment: Please clarify one point by editing and tagging: For which language do you want the code completion? For C/C++ or for Java? As those are completely independently developed plugins, they have _nothing_ to do with each other and their code completion abilities are completely different.

Comment: For C/C++. As I said originally, I know how to do it for Java (or at least as close as it's going to get), but similar functionality for C seems to be missing. But I edited my article to make this more clear.

Answer (score 3):

You can go to "Content Assist" under Preferences for your language of choice, and make sure Auto Activation is turned on. Then, decrease the delay (100ms works for me), and in the Auto Activation Triggers box, put any characters you want auto activation for. For something like Xcode, that'd be: .abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz, plus caps if you want them. Voila!